# FactoryGirl: Change an attribute after FactoryGirl.create is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In my user model, all users are assigned the role of `user` in a `before_create` callback. So I'm having a lot of trouble creating an admin user to use in some tests. Here is what I've tried, which is not working:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Exercises" do
  describe "GET /Exercises" do
    it "gives the expected status code." do
        sign_in_as_valid_user
        @user.role = 'admin'

      get exercises_path
      response.status.should be(200)
    end
```

for completeness, here is the method that is called:

```
module ValidUserRequestHelper
    def sign_in_as_valid_user
        FactoryGirl.create :program
        @user ||= FactoryGirl.create :user

        post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @user.email, 'user[password]' => @user.password
    end
end
```

and the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "test#{n}@vitogo.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email           
    password                            '12345678'
    password_confirmation '12345678'
    goal_id                             1
    experience_level_id     1
    gender                              'Female'
  end
end
```

I'm just trying to change the role in the specific tests where it matters.

Any ideas how to do this? It's been driving me crazy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's not working? Is the test failing or does it raise an error?

Comment: The test is failing because I'm trying to access a page that is only accessible to admins, so I get redirected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I then edited my users Factory to create an Admin Factory that inherited from my User Factory, then assigned the admin role in an `after(:create)` callback like this:

```
factory :user do
    email           
    password              '12345678'
    password_confirmation '12345678'
    gender                'Male'
    factory :admin do
      after(:create) { |user| user.role = 'admin'; user.save }
    end
  end
```

Comment: @zetetic. SO won't let me accept it until tomorrow. You can answer the question in a similar way and I'll give you the checkmark if you want.

Comment: sorry, forgot about the delay. Keep the points, you deserve them.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `@user` in a method, something like this in the ValidUserRequestHelper

```
def current_user
  @user
end
```

Then calling `current_user.role = 'admin'` in your specs